# Slow Python serial speed

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have connected an Arduino UNO to my raspberry pi and want to read from a connected Sensor with a Python Script.
When I try to read the sensor data from the Arduino IDE, it works perfectly fast, but with Python it is really slow.

This is my code:

```
import serial
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
ser.baudrate = 9600

a = 0
stop = False

file = open("PulseData/MasterArrayData.txt","w")
if(ser.isOpen() == False):
        ser.open()

print("Start scanning")

while stop == False:
        test = ser.readline()
        try:
                testInt = int(test)
                if testInt > 100 and testInt < 800:
                        print test
                        file.write(str(testInt))
                        file.write("\n")
                        a = a+1
        except ValueError:
                print "Not an integer"
        if(a == 400):
                stop = True
        sleep(0.1)

file.close()


call(["./main", "PulseData/MasterArrayData.txt"])
```

I already tried to use a higher baud rate, or a shorter sleeping time, without success.

I've read that the speed can be improved with PyTTY, but unfortunately I didn't find any documentation about that.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you sleeping at all?  This program does not appear to be capable of running at any speed other than the rate at which you are receiving lines of data, so I'm not sure how it could be "really slow" without completely failing to run.  Could you quantify what "really slow" means?  Is it possible that a large amount of your data is outside the 101..799 range, and therefore is getting discarded without any indication?

Comment: I'm sleeping because in the Arduino example code, there was a delay of that time as well. Really slow means I get less than 10 values per second. The values are all in the 101 to 799 range. When I run it on the Arduino IDE there are basically no values outside at all, but when I run it with Python, sometimes I get a single value like 32334 or also 5, in the middle of "normal" values. So this is just to kick those values out

Comment: Sleeping for a tenth of a second between readings is an *absolute guarantee* that you will get less than 10 readings per second.  The occasional garbage value you're getting happens when the serial port buffer inevitably overflows and characters get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [comment by jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961771/slow-python-serial-speed#comment86940414_49961771):

> Sleeping for a tenth of a second between readings is an absolute guarantee that you will get less than 10 readings per second. The occasional garbage value you're getting happens when the serial port buffer inevitably overflows and characters get lost.